CosmosDB with PyMongo replaces the array field in document with literal array filter subdocument
I'm using the CosmosDB on Azure with MongoDbApi. In my Flask service I use pymongo.
My collection consists of a documents similar to this:
{
    "file_name": "foo",
    "date": "2024-05-07",
    "count": 1,
    "deliveries": [
        {
            ...,
            "events": [
                ...
            ],
            "type": "NG"
        },
        {
            ...,
            "events": [
                ...
            ],
            "type": "Legacy"
        }
    ],
    "snapshot_timestamp": 1234567
}

I have a set of functions (basically simple queries) that update the file. An example one would be something like this:
collection.update_one(
    {
        "file_name": ...,
        "snapshot_timestamp": ...,
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "deliveries.$[outer].type": "NG",
            "deliveries.$[outer].foo": "bar",
            "count": 5
        },
        "$push": {
            "deliveries.$[outer].some_array": "some_value"
        }
    },
    upsert=True,
    array_filters=[
        {"outer.x": "y"}
    ]
)

Sometimes I see a corrupted document that looks like this:
{
    "file_name": "foo",
    "date": "2024-05-07",
    "count": 1,
    "deliveries": {
        "$[outer]": {
            ...,
            "events": [
                ...
            ],
            "type": "NG"
        },
    },
    "snapshot_timestamp": 1234567
}

I'm really trying to find the source of this, but there is no update operation where I use a single "$set": {"delivery.$[outer]"}. This happens exteremely rarely. Unfortunately I can't find any type of trace or path that causes this. Is there any way where the update() operation can cause this behavior?

hi can you wrap the $set within a []

@cmgchess I don't quite understand. What do you mean?

meant something like this

@cmgchess Thanks for this, I will try. Should I also wrap it together with the $push? Like [{$set}, {$push}] or [{$set, $push}]?

sorry but unfortunately array filter doesnt work with pipeline ([]) apparently

https://mongoplayground.net/p/1lWlNgvkoWL is this your query btw

@cmgchess Yes, it does look alike.

not sure what's causing your issue exactly, but... just be aware that you have multiple unbounded arrays in your document (an anti pattern) - consider that if these can really grow without restriction, eventually your writes will fail as you exceed maximum document size (plus manipulating those larger documents will increase RU cost over time).
